# how to get into directory ~/.acme.sh/'*.domain.com' in bash script

Tags: bash

I have been using acme.sh to generate several in-house website certificates

Of late, I am trying to automate this task.

I have the following within my bash script:

```
cd ~/.acme.sh/'"'*.domain.com"'"/
cd ~/.acme.sh/'*.domain.com'/
cd ~/.acme.sh/\'*.domain.com\'/
cd ~/.acme.sh/\'\*.domain.com\'/
```

none of these work and I am at a loss.

If I tab in the terminal, it auto-completes for me.

Comment: Presumably `echo ~/.acme.sh/*.domain.com/` is more than one directory.  You can only change into one directory.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: the directory is literally named '*.domain.com' with the quotes (in the shell) in the directory listing in thunar it is just *.domain.com

Comment: Escape it with \\*

Comment: I have updated my question with additional tries, but none work

Comment: You have something weird in your path name that you are not telling us about (maybe the literal / or whitespace).  Post post `ls -df .acme.sh/*.domain.com* | od -a` (These * are not escaped, feel free to grep before od to only show me the relevant bits).

Comment: What does TAB auto-complete to? Use that!

Comment: The second one, with single quotes and no backslashes, is what I would use myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd [dir]` is used to change the current directory.  The optional dir is a single directory.  You clarified that the directory in question had a literal '*' so escape that with `cd ~/.acme.sh/\*.domain.com/`:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.acme.sh/*.domain.com
$ cd .acme.sh/\*.domain.com/
$ pwd
/home/allan/.acme.sh/*.domain.com
```

Comment: this works in the shell (terminal) if I type *.d and hit the tab key but I am trying to do this in a bash script and it is not working

Comment: as it turns out - I was having a brain fart and thought I tried your answer and included it in my question, but I must have typed it wrong - indeed cd ~/.acme.sh/\\*.domain.com works  - looking back in my history, I was missing the .sh on  the end of .acme!  I don't have great vision